Why does an APU fitted with a load compressor consume less fuel while operating two packs instead of one (e.g 737NG)?
As far as I know, an APU that takes its bleed air from the compressor section consumes more fuel the more bleed air is extracted, like the engines. Some APUs have a load compressor for the bleed air fitted on the shaft that always spins, and on some aircraft like on the 737NG the APU consumes less fuel with both packs operating on the ground than if supplying one pack only although it needs less bleed air even if the single pack runs automatically on high setting (hence why such a great amount of unused air is then exhausted through a surge control valve (SCV)) Now I still don’t understand the reason for this phenomenon after reading multiple discussions regarding this question. Please correct me if something of the content above is wrong.

@mins  It's an accurate statement. Not sure that the explanation here sheds much light on things beyond what the OP has already read, but what's being discussed is real.

Single pack operation certainly doesn't achieve the same cooling as two packs; other than a single pack regulating to high flow in the AUTO position (which happens with engine bleeds, not APU bleed), I'm not sure how it goes about trying to do so. The way it was explained to me, matching your thought, was that the APU is optimized for the flow & pressure required to feed two packs, and feeding just one is far enough from that optimal point that it actually takes slightly more fuel. But the engineering "why" causing that, i.e. the OP's question, is beyond my knowledge.

I don't think it's related to electrical load. The screenshots of the CDU in the 737.org.uk link I posted above are accurate. You can sit on the ground with the APU running & watch the fuel flow change by turning packs on & off, with no other changes going on.

@RalphJ: Yes, in the meantime I read another information about the additional fuel consumption: +15% for single pack (source, page 28). From what I read the higher fuel flow could be required to supply the same air flow at a higher pressure (this would explain the "work harder" found everywhere on the web), to allow a single PACK to process it alone. Without an authoritative source I won't write an answer.
